# What was the "glowing package" Pym was expecting?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, when Captain Rogers and Tony go in 1970 to take the Tesseract and Pym particles, Steve calls Dr. Pym about receiving a package which he tells is glowing. This makes Pym scared and run for it.

Does anyone know what Pym was expecting?

Comment: The Kryptonite..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Radioactive stuff, most probably, as it was (supposedly, but Pym didn't seem to refute the possibility) glowing and gave the workers handling it some kind of illness.

It can be noticed that back in [*Tales to Astonish* #35 (1962)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_to_Astonish_Vol_1_35), one of the first Ant-Man comics, Pym was tasked to make a gas to render people immune to radioactivity, which probably implies studying of radioactive material first. Possibly *Endgame* was making a reference to that.

[image: Pym is tasked to develop a radioactivy immunity]

Pym has been established in the MCU to be a bit of a "mad genius" at times, tampering with iffy physics (failed Pym particles reduce their targets to goo, remember a certain sheep?). Thus, a (more boring) out-of-universe explanation is most likely to have a funny scene, where Pym and the viewers gradually realise what the package is, as the "clueless" person at the other end of the line still doesn't understand.

Comment: Tony Says to cap: "You know How I know", and then Steve know what package to talk about. I was hoping there must have been some thing explicit.

Comment: @RitWick maybe he meant the Tesseract package? I don't remember that part well, it seems. Pym likely to work on radioactive stuff can be expected by Tony and Cap though, as the guy's experiments, while genius, are a bit on the line sometimes.

Comment: Tesseract was already there for 70 years with SHIELD when Alexander Pierce says and is given to Dr. Mar-vel to work with. I am pretty sure it was not Tesseract.